# Will a standard book on ruby on rails work if I am using jRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I will have to use JDBC with an old database, which I why I selected jRuby.  If I get a book on ruby on rails that does not include jRuby information, will that be benficial to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will.  Jruby is just another Ruby implementation, so pretty much everything that works in regular Ruby will work in Jruby as well.  They have worked very hard at getting rails to run really well with Jruby  While there are some gems that currently will not run in jruby, a Ruby On Rails book will definitely be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind though is you cannot run native (C code) gems with JRuby.  However most of the popular ones have ports.